# jQuery $.post with passed variables fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
I am wondering why:

$.post("remote.php",
    {'f':a_searchtype, 'partial':value},
    function(data){
        $("#result").html(data);
});

worksfine. but using a variable such as:

ajax_arg = {'f':a_searchtype, 'partial':value};
$.post("remote.php",
    ajax_arg,
    function(data){
        $("#result").html(data);
}); 


causes javascript errors in unrelated sections of code.
```

The second version can be used in a common routine that doesn't know what is being passed.

Comment: Can you post what errors you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ajax_arg` needs to be global varible so add a var infront of it.

**ANSWER**
`var ajax_arg = {'f':a_searchtype, 'partial':value};`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the variable name 'ajax_arg' is also used some where else?  'ajax_arg' is a global variable.